# g++ linking object files cant be linked

Tags: c++, g++, linker-errors

For our assignment we've got a `list.h` file and a `list.o` file which is compiled source `list.cpp`.

I have a `me.cpp` file which is implementation of one of declared function in `list.h` and a `main.cpp` to test all of them(it is given with assignment files also)

I don't have a good makefile, actually mine is like :

```
main: LL.o list.o
    g++ -c main.cpp LL.o list.o

LL.o : me.cpp list.h
    g++ -c me.cpp
list.o : list.h
```

but when I use the make statement it returns `g++: warning: LL.o: linker input file unused because linking not done
g++: warning: list.o: linker input file unused because linking not done`
and it turns my `me.cpp` file into something really weird!
Anyone has a suggestion what should I do?

Comment: have a look at the proper use of the options `-c` and `-o` to have the correct names http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options

Answer (score 4):

`g++ -c` means "create the `.o` file, but do not actually link."

You shouldn't use this flag when you want to build `main`:

```
main: LL.o list.o main.o
  g++ main.o LL.o list.o
```

It also means you should build `main.o` first (Adding `g++ -c main.cpp -o main.o` in your Makefile)

---

Edit to take comment into account:

You should also actually build `LL.o`. You should change `g++ -c me.cpp` into `g++ -c me.cpp -o LL.o` (but it might make more sense to manipulate a `me.o` instead)

Comment: also `LL.o` needs to come from some input